# What is the meaning of a propositional variable in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Im reading the book [Logic, Mathematics and Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=AInDCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA77) by Yves Nievergelt, and in the second chapter when defining the well-formed formulae the author gives the following definition:

**Definition (well-formed formulae).** Select Select three disjoint lists of symbols.
Every symbol from the first list of symbols, which may consist of one or more letter(s) from a specified alphabet, $P, Q...$, is called a **formulaic letter**. Such formulaic letters are not parts of the predicate calculus, but they help in describing the following rules to define well-formed formulae.

Also, every symbol from the second list of symbols, which may consist of one
or more letter(s) from a specified alphabet, $A, B, ...$, is called a **propositional variable** or **sentence symbol**. (Propositional variables may later be replaced in pure calculi by functional or relational variables, or in applied calculi by atomic formulae, which may include individual variables or constants specific to applications.)

Moreover, every symbol from the third list of symbols, which may consist of one or more letter(s) from a specified alphabet, $X, Y, ...$, is called an **individual variable**.(Individual variables may later be replaced by items specific to applications, for instance, numbers in arithmetic, or points in geometry.)

Every propositional variable or atomic formula is a **well-formed** formula. For
all well-formed formulae $P$ and $Q$, and for every individual variable X, the following
four strings of symbols are also well-formed formulae:

- $\lnot (P)$
- $(P) \Rightarrow (Q)$
- $\forall X(P)$
- $\exists X(P)$

Furthermore, only strings of symbols built from letters or variables through appli-
cations of the rules W1–W4 can be well-formed formulae.

I got confused because the author dont used any symbol from the second list $A, B, ...$, Its not clear for me what the propositional variable really means in this description, but I think I need to understand it properly before proceed since he says that every propositional variable is a well-formed formula, I guess that the formulaic letters from the first list represent formulas which are constructed from propositional variables and that the propositional can but need not to contain individual variables.

I want to understand what the author really means by propositional variables/sentence symbols, and if there is a more clear way to define well-formed formulas for predicate calculus, also any tip on study of first-order logic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the author calls *formulaic letters* [$P,Q$] are usually called "metavariables": they are not part of the formal language but they are used in the text to name formulas ("formulaic letters are not parts of the predicate calculus, but they help in describing the following rules to define well-formed formulae.").

See a different example of definition of *formula*:

> $R_n(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $x=y$ are *atomic formulas*, where $R_n$ is an $n$-ary *predicate* symbol;

> if $\varphi, \psi$ are formulas, then $(\lnot \varphi)$, $(\varphi \land \psi), (\varphi \to \psi)$ and $(\varphi \lor \psi)$ are formulas,

> if $\varphi$ is a formula and $x$ is an individual variable, then $\forall x \varphi$ and $\exists x \varphi$ are formulas.

Here $x=y$ is an expression of the formal language, while $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are metavariables ("formulaic letters").

*Individual variables* [$X,Y$] are variables naming *objects* of the domain of discourse (more usually not capital letters), like in set theory: $x \in y$ (see Examples page 82).

Thus, considering examples from set theory, we have that $x \in y$ is an atomic formula and that $\lnot (x \in y)$ and $(x \in y) \lor (x \in z)$ and $\exists x \forall y \lnot (x \in y)$ are examples of formulas.

In some cases, it is useful to consider as part of the language, not only atomic formulas, like $x=y$ and $x \in y$, but also *propositional variables* (or sentence symbols, aka: $0$-ary predicate symbols).

When we will fix an interpretation $\mathfrak I$, a sentence symbol $A$ will be interpreted as a truth value.

Comment: I edited the question to reference the correct list in the end of my post, I was confuse about the non use of $A, B,..,$, I understood what he mean about the individual variables. But still confuse about the propositional variables/setence symbols.

Can you please include an example of usage of the second list in your answer?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim - IMO, the author is a little bit confused here. He writes "Propositional variables may later be replaced in pure calculi by functional or relational variables, or in applied calculi by atomic formulae, which may include individual variables or constants specific to applications." If so, in set theory the binary predicate $\in$ is a relation symbol; we abbreviate with $(x \in y)$ the "formal" $\in(x,y)$.

Comment: But in Examples page 82 the author writes $(X \in A)$, using the symbol $A$ as an individual variable. This is wrong, according to the previous definition. In conclusion, my suggestion is: follow the "usual" specification of [first-order language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax)

Comment: I was thinking to lookup for another books, as I stiil a very beginner, it turn very difficult to understand the following sections, since I failing to read and understand the text in a precise way.

I noticed some typos in the chapter about the propositional logic, but most of them dont cause any trouble. I think it was very common because because it has so much formulas, so it will be impossible to type them all without errors.

But I dont know for now, if I should still going through this one or give a try in some other book. What you think? From where you learned/learn logic?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim - many good textbooks available: [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover), [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), [Chiswell & Hodges](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/~belardinelli/Documents/Logique/Mathematical-Logic-ChiswellHodges.pdf). I do not know [Nievergelt's one](https://books.google.it/books?id=AInDCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover): only browsed it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and references.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written it seems that X,Y, etc are individual instances that satisfy a particular proposition P. Suppose P be a set of all even numbers .Then X may or may not be an instance of P according as X is even or not.